# String to Date Object PHP Laravel Carbon

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

How to make date string to date object in PHP using Carbon?

```
$minTime = DB::table('order') 
            ->select('order_creation_date', 'restaurant_id')
            ->where('restaurant_id', '=', '70')
            ->orderBy('order_creation_date', 'asc')
            ->first();

            $m = $orderDay -> month;
            $d = $orderDay -> day;
            $y = $orderDay -> year;

    $y = (int)$y;
    $d = (int)$d;
    $m = (int)$m;

    $orderDay = $minTime -> order_creation_date;
    var_dump($orderDay);
```

Error:

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

Normal Value of string:

```
string(19) "2016-02-05 14:51:30"
```

Any ideas how to fix it? I think I need make string to date object. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Using `$dates` property in `Order` model:

```
protected $dates = ['order_creation_date'];
```

Comment: It returns a `Carbon` object when dealing with `order_creation_date`. Read about Carbon. @ArnasPuidokas

Comment: It doesn't suck. I just said in colloquial Persian, purposely. @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 0):

Your error surely is on line 2

Change the order of the code:

```
$minTime = DB::table('order') 
        ->select('order_creation_date', 'restaurant_id')
        ->where('restaurant_id', '=', '70')
        ->orderBy('order_creation_date', 'asc')
        ->first();

$orderDay = $minTime -> order_creation_date;

        $m = $orderDay -> month;
        $d = $orderDay -> day;
        $y = $orderDay -> year;

$y = (int)$y;
$d = (int)$d;
$m = (int)$m;


var_dump($orderDay);
```

or when accessing the dates using DB facade, it probably doesn't return a Carbon Instance.
Try ..:

```
$orderDay = Carbon::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s",$minTime -> order_creation_date);
```

Alternatively, you should prefer to use `$dates` property in your `Order` Model..

```
protected $dates = ['order_creation_date'];
```

Comment: @arnas-puidokas Updated.. Check-Again

Comment: Trailing data in Error

Comment: @arnas-puidokas Please explain the error. More description and line no. etc

Comment: in Carbon.php line 425
at Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-n-j G:i:s', '2016-02-05 14:51:30-8-1 11:53:58', null) in Carbon.php line 368
at Carbon::create('2016-02-05 14:51:30') in DashboardController.php line 77
at DashboardController->getDashboardView()

Comment: @arnas-puidokas Oh.. use the following instruction ... `$orderDay = Carbon::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s",$minTime -> order_creation_date);`